# How can I interpret$~\tan^{}\left(x\right),\ln\left(\tan^{}\left(x\right)\right)~$with$~0<x<\pi~$? I think banned-inputs exist in this range

Tags: trigonometry

The following equation is given in the book.

$$y=\ln\left(\tan^{}\left(x\right)\right)+\sin^{-1}\left(\cos^{}\left(x\right)\right)~~\left(0<x<\pi\right)\tag{1}$$

By the way, this equation is given to let one compute $~\frac{dy}{dx}~$

The current dought for me is$~\tan^{}\left(x\right)~$with$~0<x<\pi~$

The followings are in my head.

$$-\infty<\tan^{}\left(x\right)<+\infty~~\leftrightarrow~~-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

So the value range of$~0<x<\pi~$has been really making me panicked.

Moreover, as$~\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\pi~$is held,$~\tan^{}\left(x\right)<0~$is satisfied and$~\ln\left(\tan^{}\left(x\right)\right)~$is completely can't be held.

Misprint?

Comment: $\tan(x)$ is not defined for $x=\pi/2$. And $\ln(\tan(x))$ is not real for $\pi/2<x<\pi$, so my guess is that there's a typo and it should be $0<x<\pi/2$

Comment: Further to jjagmath's remark: [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+of+%5Cln%5Cleft%28%5Ctan+x%5Cright%29%2B%5Carcsin%5Cleft%28%5Ccos+x%5Cright%29)

Comment: @jjagmath: you'd better post that as an answer, if only to counterbalance the existing answers.

Comment: I do not agree. The task is to compute the derivative. The function is only defined for $0<x<\frac \pi 2$ and so will be the derivative (which can be computed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$−∞<\tan()<+∞  ↔  −\frac{\pi}{2}<<\frac{\pi}{2}$, is assuming you are taking their limits at $x = −\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}$

The domain of this function is heavily dependent on $\ln(\tan())$, such that $\tan(x) > 0$, further more $x ≠ \frac{\pi}{2}$

$\tan(x) \leq 0$ between for $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \pi$, hence the function does not exist there, as stated by the answer above as $\ln({\mathbb{R^-} \cup {0}})$ is not real.

So you domain is further restricted to $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ (This should be it)

Note that the $\sin^{-1}(\cos(x))$ does not affect the domain above, and note that $\ln(\tan(x)) - x + \frac{\pi}{2}$ **≠** $\ln(\tan(x)) + \sin^{-1}(\cos(x))$. Do not simplfy functions like that, it will change the derivative and does **not** apply for some $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Your derivative should be $\frac{1 - \sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}$, **however** this **only** holds because your domain is $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, otherwise if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then the derivative will be $\frac{1 - |\sin(x)|\cos(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

$\tan(x)$ is not defined for $x=π/2$. And $\ln(\tan(x))$ is not real for $π/2<x<π$, so my guess is that there's a typo and it should be $0<x<π/2$